# ジャンク品ノートパソコンのBIOSパスワード解除について

Tags: bios

ジャンク品として買ったノートパソコンのBIOSにパスワードがかかっており、設定を変更することができません。パスワードの解除方法もしくはパスワードを解除せずとも設定を変更できる方法があったらご教授ください。

ノートパソコンの情報は下記の通りです。
メーカー：CLEVO
型番：N130BU
BIOS：American Megatrends Inc. 1.05.05RHA

パスワードを介さずにUbuntuは立ち上げることができる状態です。

追記
OSの情報等はOSの側から書き換える方法があるかと思って記載しました。

現在、海外のウェブサイトで見つけたrescue passwordを通す方法を試しています(asus製のマザーボードでできる方法らしいです)。しかしながら、Alt+Rが反応せず、rescue password box が表示されません。どうやらbiosのアップデートをすると解決されるようなので、それを試しています。

Comment: 回答を知らない質問者側が、解決にどんな情報が必要かを事前に知るのはとても難しいことです。よっぽど無関係な情報をたくさん書いているわけでもありませんし、結果的に関係が薄かったことをもし気になさっていたら、どうぞお気になさらず<(\_ \_)>

Comment: @774RR さんの回答にもありますが「訳あり」と書かれたモノだったのでしょうか？そうで無い場合は販売元の説明不足として返品(対応しない場合は訴訟)とかも考えら、回答も変わってきます。「訳あり」だったか、そういった制限があることの説明書きは無かったのかの追記をお願いします。

Comment: ジャンク品で訳ありと書かれていました

Comment: もう一つ。American Magatrends社のBIOSは数多くのメーカーで使用されており、かつそれぞれのメーカーで独自にカスタマイズされています。バージョン等だけでは判断するのは不可能です。BIOSパスワードなどのハード対応はメーカーおよび販売時期によって大きく異なるため、メーカーと機器の型番を明記してください。

Comment: マシンについての情報を追記しました。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。中古品とジャンク品では扱いが全く異なります。ジャンク品は起動できなくても文句は言えない品ですので、質問内で明記するように書き換えています。

Answer (score 5):

その中古 PC 「訳アリ」格安とか書かれていませんでしたか？

１０年以上前の PC だとパスワードを含む BIOS 設定が電池バックアップ式なものがあります。つまり分解してバックアップ電池を外して数分放置することで、全設定（パスワードを含む）が消去できるようなものもあります。試してみる価値はあるかもしれません。

もちろん、電源なしでデータを維持できる不揮発性メモリにパスワードが保存されていたら、バックアップ電池を外してもパスワードは解除されません。今どきの PC は、ユーザーが求めるセキュリティ要件が厳しくなっているのでこっちになっているはず。

もしパスワードが消せてもリスクはいっぱいあります。

マザーボードのシリアル番号も一緒に消えてしまうと Windows のデジタルライセンス認証も消えてしまいます。ハードディスクの CHS/LBA 設定が変わると論理セクタと物理セクタの対応が変わってしまい全データが失わる可能性があります。時計が狂うと PKI 証明書が無効になって https 通信がすべて失敗するようになります。

というわけで（なぜマイナス投票がついているのか理解しがたいですが） @わわい さんの「パスワードは設定を変更させないためのもの」に１票で、

- メーカーに修理を依頼する（保証書が無いと断られる可能性大）
- 壊すリスクを承知の上で分解・電池抜きを試してみる
- 諦めて今のまま使う

の３つの選択肢があります。

---

stackoverflow で訊いてる以上は「パスワードを解除するプログラムを作りたい」という質問であるならば、犯罪を助長しかねないので回答できません。

---

特定の機種？だと BIOS パスワード解除サービスなんてのを行っている業者があったり（マザーボードから EEPROM を半田ごてで外して書き換えして戻す）しますが、当然有償です。まあ興味があれば検索してみてください。そのコストと期間を考えると別途安い中古 PC を買ったほうが手早かったりしなかったり・・・

Answer (score 4):

参考までに、関連サイト (Super User) に類似の質問があります。
[How to delete BIOS password? - Super User](https://superuser.com/q/964062)

既に挙がっている他の回答と重複するものを除くと、[CmosPwd](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/CmosPwd) というユーティリティがあります。
コマンドラインのユーティリティですが、OSが起動しているなら Ubuntu 向けの [パッケージも提供されています](https://packages.debian.org/ja/jessie/cmospwd)。

思いつくキーワードで検索するだけで日本語での解説記事もヒットしますが、以下のサイトではノートPCの場合の注意書きがありました。

[「CmosPwd」の使い方](https://pctrouble.net/software/cmospwd.html)

> ノートパソコンでは、BIOSパスワードがCMOSではなくEEPROMに保存されていることがあります。
>   このような場合、CMOSクリアを行なっても、BIOSパスワードは解除されません。

Comment: 試しましたが、うまく行かなかったのでrescue passwordを試しています。

Answer (score 2):

パスワードというのは、設定を変更できなくするために掛けるものです。

メーカに修理対応してもらいましょう

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntuは無関係ですし、BIOSバージョンも無意味です。

メーカー名と型番から、取扱説明書を入手してください。その中にパスワードリセット方法が記載されている場合があります。
取扱説明書によくある記載として

- メーカー修理（わわいさんの回答）
- 電池を外す（774RRさんの回答）

が挙げられている状況です。